# ¿Se dice "positiva o negativamente" o "positivamente o negativamente"?

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, sintaxis, adverbios

Me topé con la siguiente duda realizando un ensayo: ¿cuál es la forma correcta de escribir el siguiente oración:

> Independientemente de si la partícula que está cargada *positivamente o negativamente*, la magnitud del potencial seguirá un comportamiento muy concreto en los puntos límite.

o

> Independientemente de si la partícula que está cargada *positiva o negativamente*, la magnitud del potencial seguirá un comportamiento muy concreto en los puntos límite.

Entiendo que la segunda forma suena mucho más natural, pero no he encontrado una respuesta satisfactoria buscando en Google. Estaría muy agradecido si me pudieran ayudar con bibliografía acerca de esto o con la respuesta directamente.

Comment: Las dos opciones son válidas. Hubo hace no mucho una pregunta similar en el sitio. Allí se dan referencias. Mira a ver si responde a tu pregunta.

Comment: De hecho iría bien tener una canónica sobre cuándo se usa *-mente*, reglas y usos (o recomendaciones). Mi pregunta era más sobre el caso concreto de cuando hay tres o más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando en una frase han de emplearse dos vocablos seguidos con el adverbio -mente, únicamente se pone al final del último adjetivo (aunque se admite la repetición de la terminación

> El candidato contesta a las preguntas **clara** y **correctamente**.

> Hay que defender la industria lechera tanto **interior** como **exteriormente**.

> […] el Gobierno, mal que les pese a los opositores, es el que está en posición de capitalizar más **rápida** y **eficientemente** ese enojo colectivo [La Nación (Argentina), acceso: 28-11-2012].

Fuente: [Blog de lengua: Coordinación de adverbios acabados en -mente](https://blog.lengua-e.com/2012/coordinacion-de-adverbios-en-mente/)

En las comparativas de desigualdad, se entiende la elipsis del elemento compositivo en el primer adverbio: más **rápida** que **pausadamente**.

Fuente: [Centro Virtual Cervantes](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=52588)

Por lo que entiendo que en tu caso la forma preferible sería

> la partícula que está cargada **positiva** o **negativamente**